# Blocking queue design 

Tags: java, design-patterns, queue

n threads produce to a `BlockingQueue`.
When the queue is full, the consumer drains the queue and does some processing.

How should I decide between the following 2 choices of implementation?

Choice A : 
The consumer regularly polls the queue to check if it is full, all writers waiting (it is a blocking queue after all : ).

Choice B : 
I implement my own queue with a synchronized "put" method. Before putting the provided element, I test if the queue is not nearly full (full minus 1 element). I then put the element and notify my consumer (which was waiting).

The first solution is the easiest but does polling ; which annoys me.
The second solution is in my opinion more error prone and more requires more coding.

Comment: You can also use some other means to communicate "start processing", e.g. CountdownLatch. Also, why can't consumer just fetch all elements, and decide when to start processing them on its own (e.g. after having N elements?)

Comment: My consumer would then consume all elements as they come and when he has reached a certain number of elements, he processes them.
In that case, he would be always working and trying to reach the limit 
I like that one :) I'll give it a try and see how it works...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to write your proxy queue which would wrap a queue instance internally along with an Exchanger instance. Your proxy methods delegate calls to your internal queue. Check if the internal queue is full when you add and when it is full, exchange the internal queue with the consumer thread. The consumer thread will exchange an empty queue in return for the filled queue. Your proxy queue will continue filling the empty queue while the consumer can keep processing the filled queue. Both activities can run in parallel. They can exchange again when both parties are ready.

```
class MyQueue implements BlockingQueue{
    Queue internalQueue = ...
    Exchanger<Queue> exchanger;

    MyQueue(Exchanger<BlockingQueue> ex){
    this.exchanger = ex;
    }

     .
     .
     .

    boolean add (E e) {
      try{
        internalQueue.add(e);
      }catch(IllegalStateException ise){
        internalQueue = exchanger.exchange(internalQueue);
      }
      internalQueue.add(e);     
    }

}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Queue currentQueue = new empty queue;
        while (...){
           Object o = currentQueue.remove();
           if (o == null){
              currentQueue = exchanger.exchange(currentQueue);
              continue;
           }
           //cast and process the element
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to use Exceptions for control flow? That's generally a bad idea and frowned upon.

Comment: The code is just indicative with no intention of providing an implementation but just to give an idea. But, well you are right!

Comment: I like this option of having 2 queues, I used it recently in a C++ embedded environment and it really reduces locking contention between the producer and consumer. Instead of the exception, I did a simple check when adding to the queue.

Comment: Well, you can use offer() and check its return value for indication on whether the queue is full.

Answer (score 0):

The second solution is obviously better. And it is not so complicated. You can inherit or wrap any other `BlockingQueue` and override its method `offer()` as following: call the "real" offer(). If it returns `true`, exit. Otherwise trigger the working thread to work and immediately call `offer()` with timeout.

Here is the almost pseudo code:

```
public boolean offer(E e) {
    if (queue.offer(e)) {
        return true;
    }
    boolean result = queue.offer(e, timeout, unit); // e.g. 20 sec. - enough for worker to dequeue at least one task from the queue, so the place will be available.
    worker.doYouJob();
    return result; }
```

Comment: I thought of that one but between the 1st offer which returns false and my second "offer", I may be stuck once more since there are other threads which may fill my queue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is there such implementation of queue you need: consumer are wait while queue become full and only when it full drain and start processing.

You queue should be blocked for consumers until it become full. Think you need to override drain() method to make it wait while queue become full. Than your consumers just call and wait for drain method. No notification from producer to consumer is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use an observer pattern. Have your consumers register with the queue notifier. When a producer does a put the queue would then decide whether to notify any listeners.

Answer (score 0):

I used the CountdownLatch which is simple and works great.
Thanks for the other ideas :)